# user_impersonation scope - why?

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, authorization

Usually, when reading about OAuth2, you can find information that the permission should be defined in scopes to state exactly what is needed. I recently looked into how Microsoft does that in their Azure Portal. It turns out that the only scope I get when accessing the portal is "user_impersonation". Why is that? My guess is that the token would be too big if they included all the permissions as scopes?

More generally, it seems to me that there are at least two approaches to dealing with authorization in OAuth2:

1. Store all permissions in the token - the Resource Server just looks at the token to decide what data to expose
2. Store limited information in the token (like userId) - the Resource Server has to find permissions in some data base related to the provided userId in the token.

It seems that Microsoft is using the second approach. Unfortunately, I didn't find any information about that way of doing auth. Are there some good resources to read about it?
Until now, as I said, all resources I read say that you should include the permissions as scopes.

Comment: I think this is quite an opinionated topic. Ultimately developers will choose whichever approach is feasible and doable within the constraints of the project. For the Azure Portal case including all of the user permissions in the token would not only be impossible due to header length restrictions, but also because it would mean that changes to permissions would not be visible until you got a new token.

Comment: Also it is important to remember that Azure Portal is just one of the client apps that use Azure AD. Office 365 and thousands of other apps use it as well. Which means it offers a generic solution for user roles etc. that works for some of the use cases. Azure Portal team would not be able to implement the same RBAC system on the current capabilities offered by Azure AD.

Comment: @juunas Good point about the necessity to re-login to see changes! I don't think the question is opinionated, I don't specify anywhere what my preference is, honestly, I don't even have any preference here! I rather wanted to confirm if my understanding is correct and find out if there are some resources where I could learn more about that topic.

Answer (score 5):

For the API permissions of most of the services in Azure Portal, you can see **User_Impersonation** delegated permission. This is because **user_impersonation** permission is enough to access that particular service API on behalf of the signed user

For the other services like Microsoft Graph, you can see many other permissions like **user.read,** **user.readwrite** etc.,

While generating the access token in OAuth flow, you can add the scope with the permissions added for the app registration. The token will be generated with these permissions.

Comment: Is there a way to get the UUID for user_impersonation? I am trying to get this ID for Dynamics 365 CRM?